# Question related with partial order - finite set - minimal element

Tags: elementary-set-theory, induction, order-theory

**Prove by induction**. Every **partial order** on a **nonempty finite** set has at least one **minimal** element.

How can I solve that question ?

Answer (score 8):

One proof method (by induction) is on the size of your set.

The basis, a singleton. There is only one element so clearly it is minimal.
Assume the claim is true for sets of size $n$, now prove for $n+1$:
Choose any element of $A$, denote it by $a$ now restrict your partial order to $A\setminus\{a\}$. By the induction hypothesis there is a minimal element there, $b$. Now look at the original order - if $a<b$ show that $a$ is minimal, otherwise $b$ is still minimal.

Either way, you found a minimal element in $A$ and your partial order.