# A finite set always has a maximum and a minimum.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, order-theory

I am pretty confident that this statement is true. However, I am not sure how to prove it. Any hints/ideas/answers would be appreciated.

Comment: See [Every finite set...](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/259893/every-finite-set-contains-its-supremum-proof-improvement)

Comment: Suppose there is no maximal element then what happens? For every element $x \in S$,you can always find $ y \in S$ such that $x<y$.So,...

Comment: You mean a **nonempty** finite set?

Comment: isn't this weierstrass theorem?

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24996/question-related-with-partial-order-finite-set-minimal-element

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Let $S = \{s_1, \ldots,s_n\}$ be a **nonempty** finite set of size $n > 0$. We will show by induction on $n \in \mathbb N$ that there exist some $m,M \in S$ such that for all $s \in S$, we have that $m \leq s \leq M$.

**Base Case:** For $n=1$, we have $S = \{s_1\}$, so taking $m = s_1$ and $M=s_1$ trivially satisfies the required condition.

**Induction Hypothesis:** Assume that the claim holds for $n=k$, where $k \geq 1$.

It remains to prove that the claim holds true for $n = k+1$. To this end, choose any set $S$ with $k+1$ elements, say $S = \{s_1 ,\ldots,s_k,s_{k+1}\}$. Now by the induction hypothesis, the subset:
$$
S' = S \setminus \{s_{k+1}\} = \{s_1 ,\ldots,s_k\}
$$
has a minimum element and a maximum element. That is, we know that there exists some $m',M' \in S'$ such that for all $s' \in S'$, we have that $m' \leq s' \leq M'$. Now observe that $s_{k+1}$ must fall under $1$ of $3$ cases:

**Case 1:** Suppose that $s_{k+1} < m'$. Then take $m = s_{k+1}$ and $M=M'$. To see why this works, observe that any element in $S$ is either $s_{k+1}$ or some $s' \in S'$, and:
$$
m = s_{k+1} < m' \leq s' \leq M' =M
$$

**Case 2:** Suppose that $m' \leq s_{k+1} \leq M'$. Then take $m = m'$ and $M=M'$. To see why this works, observe that any element in $S$ is either $s_{k+1}$ or some $s' \in S'$, and:
$$
m = m' \leq s_{k+1} \leq M' = M
$$
$$
m = m' \leq s' \leq M' = M
$$

**Case 3:** Suppose that $s_{k+1} > M'$. Then take $m =m'$ and $M=s_{k+1}$. To see why this works, observe that any element in $S$ is either $s_{k+1}$ or some $s' \in S'$, and:
$$
m = m' \leq s' \leq M' < s_{k+1} = M
$$

Hence, we have shown that $S$ has a minimum and maximum element, as desired.

Comment: I see where you are coming from, and your proof is through. Thank you for taking the time for answering this. However, I am not really sure whether I can use proof for induction when such elements are not in $\mathbf{N}$. Some time in the past, I tried to use a similar method for proving a statement about $\mathbf{R}$ and was told that I couldn't use proof by induction. I found this link which says otherwise and is pretty through: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4202/induction-on-real-numbers. Would you mind elaborating on why do you think induction would work in this case?

Comment: It is true that you cannot use induction on a set where well-ordering does not hold, such as the real numbers. However, notice that my proof uses induction on $n \in \mathbb N$, and induction holds for the natural numbers due to well-ordering. We are NOT inducting on the elements of $S$ (for all we know, each $s_i \in S$ could be real numbers, or matrices, or purple hippos).

Comment: Are you then implying that a finite set on $\mathbf{R}$ does not always have a maximum and a minimum?

Comment: No, I'm not. As I have proven, finite sets on $\mathbb R$ always have a maximum and a minimum. I suspect that you are confusing the set that we are induction on (that is, the natural numbers, since finite sets always have a cardinality that belongs to $\mathbb N$) with the set that the elements of $S$ belong to (say, the real numbers).

Comment: I have a question here: Why the finitude of the set forces the existence of the minimal and maximal elements?

Comment: A set S being finite means that there is a bijection between its elements and a natural number. If every pair of elements of S can be compared, then they can be ordered by the elements of a natural number. Every n+1= {0,1,..., n}, so ordering S, just says there's a 0th and an nth element which is exactly what we want. He assumes that S'=S-{x} has a maximal and a minimal element. He then compares x with, the maximum and the minimum, it either is a new maximum or a new minimum, or it itsn't, but S always has a maximum and minimum. This works because of induction regardles of the nature of S.

Comment: I guess the proof here assumes there's an order relation on the elements of S.

Comment: Every finite set doesn’t have a maximum element because “maximum” only makes sense if an order is defined on the set. Every linearly ordered finite set has a greatest element.

Answer (score 3):

Let $F$ be a finite set. if $F$ is $\{x\} $ then we are done since we vacouly have $x \geq x $ and hence $x = \max \{ x \} $. If $F = \{ a_1 ,... a_n \} $. assume they are different, otherwise we are back again to singleton case. Now, take $a_1$. IF $a_1 $ is greater than any other $a_i$ then set $a_1 = \max F $ and we are done. IF not, take $a_2$, and repeat previous step. Continue in this manner inductively. Eventually, we get the max.

Answer (score 1):

One needs to be careful about the set where to work, and the definition of the ordering. If the set is well ordered, then [the above proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/548827/665167) works fine. Otherwise, it can happen that there is a supremum, but not a maximum. We can, for example, consider the partial ordering on the set of $2\times 2$ real-valued matrices, where two matrices $A$ and $B$ are such that $A\le B$  if and only if all the entries of $B-A$ are non-negative.

With the above-mentioned order relation and set, we consider the subset
$$ E = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0& 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0& 1 \end{pmatrix} \right\} .$$

We can see that $E$ is bounded from above (by $ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0& 1 \end{pmatrix}$ for example), and from below( by $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0& 0 \end{pmatrix}$ for example). However, the two elements of $E$ are not comparable using the defined order relation, so none of them is the maximum.

Comment: If you really want to argue this silly point, a simpler and clearer example is $\{ \text{potato}, \text{bicycle}\}$.

Comment: That's a good point! One must be careful when dealing with order theory. By the way, did you mean "if the set is totally ordered" ? Instead of "well ordered"

Answer (score 0):

I would just say based on Suppes, that use of induction to prove this conjecture begs the question for the following reasons:

1. The minimality or maximality of the elements within a set, A, cannot be defined without specifying an ordering relation, R, on A.
2. Different R's will yield different minimal elements, called R-minimal elements.
3. Set A only has a unique R-minimal element iff all its non-empty subsets have unique R-minimal elements, R is connected, and R is asymmetric. (i.e. R is a well ordering)
4. Having a unique R-minimal element does not guarantee a unique R-maximal element unless A is finite.

Set A is finite iff every non-empty family of subsets of A has a minimal element [ordered by strict inclusion '$\subset$']- A. Tarski via Suppes

Furthermore, if one such family of subsets, F, has a minimal element , then it must also have a maximal element via the following argument:

If F has a minimal element, then construct G from the elements of F where z is an element of G iff for some y in F, z is Union F - y.   If z is minimal in G, then y is maximal in F, and vice versa.  If F does not have a maximal element, then G cannot have a minimal element, but G does have a minimal element, hence contradiction, and the theorem is proved.

Comment: Sorry, but this proves nothing. Besides, proving the statement in the question by induction ***is*** the way to go.

Comment: Sorry, but induction is actually proved from this theorem, so using it begs the question.

Comment: Suppes uses Tarski's definition of a finite set, which is:  A set is finite iff all its non-empty families of subsets have a minimal element.  Thus G and F must have minimal elements if the set is finite.  But if one doesn't have a maximal element, then the other can't have a minimal element, which contradicts Tarski's definition.

Comment: And I quote from Suppes et al.  "The proof of the theorem about induction for finite sets is facilitated by having available the already defined notion of maximal element of a family of subsets."

Comment: There's no hint in the question that Tarski's definition is used and I find it unlikely. Anyway, the argument you sketch should be better written.

Comment: Then what makes a set finite?  Tarski's definition is the only one that does not require choice, ordinals, or induction.  Minimality and maximality define finite.

Answer (score -7):

I suppose you mean a set of numbers, $S=\{s_1,s_2,\dots,s_n\}$ and $n$ is the finite size, just let

$$
m=\min(s_1,s_2,\dots,s_n)
$$
$$
M=\max(s_1,s_2,\dots,s_n)
$$
Q.E.D.

Comment: How do you know that $m$ and $M$ even exist? This *exactly* what the question asks.

Comment: This is standard stuff, the min and max functions for a finite number of arguments is well defined

Comment: How do you prove they are well-defined? The question is *essentially* requiring to show that you can do that. The answer by ILoveMath use an approach similar to yours, but with an actual proof that this is well-defined for any finite number of arguments. You can't just reduce something to an equivalent problem and call it a proof, especially if you don't actually solve that equivalent problem.

Comment: ok I define them:$$
\min(s_1,s_2,\dots,s_n)=\min(\min(s_1,\dots,s_{n-1}),s_n)
$$
 similarly for the maximum.

Comment: Yes, that's fine, but it *is* an inductive definition, and the question is about a rigorous proof that a finite set has minimum and maximum. So the inductive argument needs to be brought up. You can't avoid it, and your answer sweeps this under the rug.

Comment: Precisely! induction

Comment: Which appears in details in the two answers there were there two years before you posted your answer; and does not appear in your answer at all.

Comment: My point is that in every proof there are some things that we consider trivial and these are the starting point (see Richard Feynman). In my opinion the min and max functions don't need any introduction. Indeed one might question if we can define them for any finite set. What's the min({1},{1,2})? You didn't specify "set of real numbers". But even if you do that one can ask how are real numbers defined and so on. Some things are just assumed and I assumed that. I would allocate full marks in an exam if the student mentioned that.

Comment: Sure, and I wouldn't expect anyone to prove to me that this is well-defined when I referee a paper. I would, however, expect someone who is asking *why* a finite set has a minimum and maximum (and clearly, the real analysis tag means this is a set of real numbers) expect the answer to be more than "well, just apply the minimum and maximum functions to the set" which is circular and terrible. And if someone would have written me this answer in a set theory exam, they would have received exactly 0 points for it.