# Peano's Axioms and Induction

Tags: induction, peano-axioms

I was reading Landau's *Foundations of Analysis*. He starts his construction of number systems by stating five axioms. My question is related to the fifth, the axiom of induction:

*Let there be given a set $\mathscr{N}$, of natural numbers with the following properties*:

I) *1 belongs to $\mathscr{N}$*

II) *If $x$ belongs to $\mathscr{N}$ then so does $x'$*

*Then $\mathscr{N}$ contains all the natural numbers*

(Here $x'$ is the successor of $x$ )

Now consider the following  proposition:

Let $(A,≤)$ be an ordered set. If $S$ is a finite subset of $A$ then $S$ contained a maximum and a minimum.

This can be proved by induction on the cardinal of $S$. **Now my (first) question is**, for the induction to "work" is it necessary to first prove that each $S$ has an unique cardinal? That is, that there is an unique $n\in \Bbb{N}$ such that there exists a bijection between $S$ and $\left \{ 1, \cdots ,n \right \}$.

In accordance with the axiom of induction we would be forming the set: 
$$\mathscr{N}=\left \{ n \in \Bbb{N} : S\subset A \ \wedge \ \#(S)=n \Rightarrow S \ \text{contains a maximum and a minimum}   \right \}$$

Is this correct?

Now, for my second (third) question, consider Bernoulli's inequality:

$$\prod_{i=1}^{n}(1+a_i)≥1+\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i \, \quad \text{if $a_i≥-1$, $i=1,...n$}$$

If I wanted to construct the set $\mathscr{N}$ cited in the axiom, how would I do it? Furthermore, should any care be taken when defining the set, analogous to proving that the cardinal is unique in the previous question?

Comment: Was that an error when you wrote ", of natural numbers" ?  It seems to beg the question.

Comment: @DanielV I copied it exactly as it is from the text. Landau refrains from using set symbols such as $\in$, $\subset$ or $\cap$ throughout the whole book, and states everything in plain english. So "of natural numbers" means $\mathscr{N} \subset \Bbb{N}$

Comment: Not having Landau's book, could you fill in how he defines "finite set"? Also is the "ordered set" assumed to be well-ordered by $\le$, or maybe at least totally ordered, etc.?

Comment: @coffeemath He doesn't, that proposition is not from Landau's book, which is entirely devoted to constructing number systems (rationals, integers, reals, complex). I just mentioned the book as a reference for the axiom of induction. As I was reading the book this question came to my mind.
By $(A,≤)$ being an ordered set I mean that $≤$ is an order relation: it is reflexive, anti-symetric and transitive.

Comment: Reveillark: Just having a partial order doesn't guarantee existence of maxima/minima in a finite subset. For example consider the set $A=\{\ \{1\},\ \{2\}, \{1,2\}\  \}$ as a (finite)subset of the power set of naturals ordered by taking $\le$ as inclusion. Then $A$ does not have a minimal element.

Comment: @coffeemath You are absolutely right, thank you very much. I had to re check this answer http://math.stackexchange.com/a/548827/122262 to see what I was missing. 
If I don't know that the set is totally ordered then I cannot conclude that one of the three cases considered there (aka the tricotomy law), right? Is $≤$ being a total order enough to reach the desired conclusion, or do I need $A$ to be well ordered?

Comment: Reveillark: My immediate intuition is that it is enough if any two elements in the partially ordered set are "comparable", i.e. either $x \le y$ or $y \le x$ holds for any pair $x,y.$ Then an inductive style proof should work, provided one has an explicit definition of what a "finite" subset of $A$ is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, for this purpose you don't need to prove that a finite set has a unique cardinality. It is enough to define a finite set as one that is equinumerous with $\{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$ for *some* $n$. If we ever find a set that is equinumerous with both $\{1,2,3,\ldots,42\}$ and $\{1,2,3,\ldots,108\}$, then that set will just be finite in two different ways. (In reality, that's an impossible situation, of course. But *knowing* that it's impossible is not necessary for the definition to work here).

Your definition of $\mathscr N$ is problematic, because you have forgotten a quantifier for $S$, so it looks like $\mathscr N$ is something that depends on the value of $S$. What you want is something like
$$ \mathscr N = \{ n\in\mathbb N \mid \forall S\subseteq A. S\cong\{1,2,3,\ldots,n\} \Rightarrow S \text{ has maximum and minimum} \} $$
were $\cong$ denotes the existence of a bijection between the two sets. Note that the notation $S\cong\{1,2,3,\ldots n\}$ instead of $\#S=n$ allows us to remain ignorant whether some sets might have more than one cardinality.

Once we know that $\mathscr N=\mathbb N$, then it's not a problem if we were to find a freak $S$ that's equinumerous with both $\{1,2,\ldots,42\}$ and $\{1,2,\ldots,108\}$. All that would mean is that we'd have two different ways to know that $S$ has a maximum and a minimum, namely either to appeal to $42\in\mathscr N$ or to appeal to $108\in\mathscr N$.

---

Note that in *actual* proofs by induction we don't actually write down a definition of a named set $\mathscr N$. Instead we just say something like "we will now prove
$$ \forall S\subseteq A. S\cong\{1,2,3,\ldots,n\} \Rightarrow S \text{ has maximum and minimum} $$
for all $n$ by induction on $n$", and then give the proofs that $1$ has the property and that the successor of any $n$ with the property itself has it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I know that we never write down the set when doing a proof by induction, but I wanted to see how it would look (and any technicalities that might appear) if we wanted to write down a definition for the set for some reason. For my second question, would something like:

$\mathscr{N}=\left \{ n \in \Bbb{N} : \forall(a_1,...a_n) \in \Bbb{R}^n, (a_1,...a_n) \in [-1,+\infty)^n \Rightarrow \prod_{i=1}^{n}(1+a_i) ≥ 1 + \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i    \right \}$

work?

Comment: @Reveillark: Yes, something like that.