# Closest rational number to a real number in a nonempty finite set of rational numbers

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

**Question:** Let $S$ be a finite nonempty set of rational numbers, with minimal and maximal elements $s_1$ and $s_2$, respectively. Consider $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $s_1\leq\alpha\leq s_2$. Prove that of all the members of $S$ there is one closest to $\alpha$.

*Note:* This question is due to the bolded portion of a proof from Spivak's *Calculus* text (see below).

---

I am reading through Spivak's *Calculus* and the question above occurred to me while reading his proof that 
$$
\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=0,
$$
where it is assumed that $0<x<1$ and $0<a<1$ and $f$ is defined by
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $x$ is irrational},\\[0.5em]
\frac{1}{q} & \text{if $x=\frac{p}{q}$ in lowest terms}.
\end{cases}
$$
His proof is essentially as follows:

> **(Spivak proof):** Consider any $\epsilon>0$. Let $n$ be a natural number so large so that $1/n\leq\epsilon$. The only numbers $x$ for which $|f(x)-0|<\epsilon$ could be false are:
>   $$
> \frac{1}{2};\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3}; \frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4}; \frac{1}{5},\frac{2}{5},\frac{3}{5},\frac{4}{5};\ldots;\frac{1}{n},\ldots,\frac{n-1}{n}.
> $$
>   If $a$ is rational, then $a$ might be one of these numbers. However many of these numbers there may be, there are, at any rate, only finitely many. **Therefore, of all these numbers, one is closest to $a$**; that is, $|p/q-a|$ is smallest for one $p/q$ among these numbers. If $a$ happens to be one of these numbers, then consider only the values $|p/q-a|$ for $p/q\neq a$. This closest distance may be chosen as the $\delta$. For if $0<|x-a|<\delta$, then $x$ is *not* one of 
>   $$
> \frac{1}{2},\ldots,\frac{n-1}{n}
> $$
>   and therefore $|f(x)-0|<\epsilon$ *is* true, thus concluding the proof.

Perhaps I am just being paranoid, but doesn't the portion of his proof in bold need some justification? I will assume that a finite set has a minimum and a maximum (I read [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548806/a-finite-set-always-has-a-maximum-and-a-minimum)), but Spivak seems to make use of the claim in my question at the top of this post. How does one prove that such a "closest element to $a$" exists? Is there some very trivial proof by contradiction? Is there some result that relies on sophisticated knowledge of bounds or topology that would leave Spivak to exclude that from a mostly basic chapter on limits (before he introduces bounds and all that)? Any sort of rigorous justification (or referral to other literature) for his proof and/or the question at the top would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, the answer to your question is in the sentence that directly follows the bolded part of your quote:

> ...that is, |p/q−a| is smallest for one p/q among these numbers.

The minimum element of the set $\{|\alpha - s|: s \in S\}$ is $|\alpha - s^*|$ for some $s^* \in S$. Then $s^*$ is the closest element of $S$ to $\alpha$.

Comment: Oh interesting. For whatever reason I completely blanked on applying my reading of that linked thread...since $S$ is finite, then the set of distances $M=\{d(\alpha,s) \mid \alpha\in\mathbb R, s\in S\}$ will be finite. Assuming the result proved in that linked thread, I know there will be a minimal element of $M$. The $s\in S$ that corresponds to this minimal element of $M$ is the closest rational number to $\alpha$. That's what you were emphasizing yes?

Comment: Yes, exactly :)

Answer (score 1):

What he really needs is that there is an interval $(\alpha-\epsilon,\alpha + \epsilon)$ that includes none of them aside from possibly $\alpha$ itself.  As there are only finitely many, you can collect all the differences, find the minimum, divide it by $2$ and use that for $\epsilon$.  One could argue the statement is wrong because there could be two at equal distance from $\alpha$ but you can just use either one of them and the proof goes through.