# Prove that $\inf G \in G$

Tags: real-analysis

I have the following question
Suppose that G is a nonempty finite set of $\mathbb{R}$ Prove that $\inf G \in G$

My current though is is that
if we use the induction of n, the number of elements of $G$. If $G$ has some element that is $G = \{x\}$ Then $\inf G = x \in G$.

Comment: What does " If G has some element that is G=x" mean?

Comment: Why did just edit out your proof??????

Comment: @fleablood I thought that it was wrong. Do you know how to prove this?

Comment: If you want to have {} display in Mathjax write them with \ before them.  \$G=\{x\}\$ will render as $G=\{x\}$.   BUt \$G={x}\$ will render as $G={x}$.

Comment: I think your proof was *almost* right.  But worded badly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution assumes that you are *allowed* to use the following fact:

For any non-empty finite subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}$, the minimum of $S$ exists.

For a proof of this fact, see this old question:
[A finite set always has a maximum and a minimum.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548806/a-finite-set-always-has-a-maximum-and-a-minimum)

**Hint**: Since $G$ is nonempty and finite, its minimum $\min G$ exists. Because $\min G\in G$ by definition, all you need to show is that $\min G =\inf G$.

---

Now you can follow the definition of the infimum. Let $a=\min G$.

- Then for any $g\in G$, you have $a\le g$. Hence $a$ is a lower bound of $G$.
- Now suppose $a'$ is another lower bound of $G$. Since $a\in G$, you have $a'\leq a$.

To conclude that proof, note that the above argument shows that $a$ is the greatest lower bound for $G$.

Comment: "Since G is nonempty and finite, its minimum minG exists. " Why?  "all you need to show is that minG=infG."  If $\min S$ exist then $\min$ = \inf S$.  I think the heart of this question is proving every finite set of real has in minimum element.

Comment: This answer seems correct to me.

Comment: @fleablood I pretty much had the same 'why?' question as you did.  It's easy to see how people can disagree with what exactly a proof consists in, when not everyone is convinced.

Comment: Sorry, so how do you conclude this proof?

Comment: @npdfe: check the update.

Comment: "This solution assumes that you are allowed to use the following fact"  I have no idea why you would assume the user would be allowed to assume that.  It's *not* an axiom.

Comment: @fleablood: You can prove it if you like. We must assume *something* in order to give an answer. Otherwise, we would be forced to begin with the ZFC axioms and write a book for an answer.

Comment: @user798202 thanks you!

Comment: @npdfe: you are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

A property of the real numbers is that of connexity:

For all pairs of real numbers (a, b), either (a <= b) or (a >= b).

Thus, for any finite set F, all possible pairs of numbers can get compared such that there exists a number n such that n <= x, for all x in F.

Since, that holds there exists a number n which is the minimum of F.

From here show that any minimum of a set is also an infimum of that set.

Answer (score 0):

This is true for all sets with order $k=1$.

If $|G| = 1$ then there is an $x\in \mathbb R$ so that $G= \{x\}$.  Now $x \le x$ as $x$ is the only element in $G$ that means $x \le a$ for all $a\in G$.

If we assume it is true for all sets of order $k$:

Let $|G| = k+1$.  Let $x_0\in G$.  Then $|G\setminus\{x_0\}| = k$ so $G\setminus\{x_0\}$ has a minimum element.  Let's label it $m$.

$x_0\ne m$ as $x_0 \not \in G\setminus\{x_0\}$ and the elements of a set must be distinct. So either $x_0 > m$ or $x_0 < m$.

If $x_0 > m$ then for any $a \in G= G\setminus\{x_0\}\cup \{x_0\}$ either $a = x_0$ and $m < a_0$.  Of $a\ne x_0$ and $a \in G\setminus\{x_0\}$ and $m = \min G\setminus\{x_0\} \le a$.  Either way $m \le a$ so $m = \min G$.

If however $x_0 < m$ then for any $a\in G$ either $a=x_0$ and $x_0 \le a$ or $a\in G\setminus\{x_0\}$ and $x_0 < m \le a$.  Either way $x_0 \le a$ so $x_0 = \min G$.

So $\min G$ always exist.

And as $\min G \le a$ for any $a \in G$ then $\min G$ is a lower bound of $G$.  And if $k> \min G$ then $\min G \in G$ and $\min G < k$ so $k$ is not a lower bound.

So $\min G$ is the $\inf G$.